# В чем отличие ImmutableList от Guava и Collections.unmodifiableList ()?

Tags: java, коллекции

Объясните, пожалуйста, есть ли какие-то **отличия** `ImmutableList` от Guava и `Collections.unmodifiableList()`?

Есть ли какие-то **преимущества в использовании** `com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList` перед `java.util.Collections.unmodifiableList`, или же между ними нет никакой разницы в части immutability, и они полностью взаимозаменяемы?

Answer (score 3):

Тема, поднятая в вопросе, на самом деле довольно глубокая и местами запутанная. Даже терминология immutable (неизменяемый) и unmodifiable (немодифицируемый) иногда плавает у создателей JDK/библиотек. Что же касается конкретно вашего вопроса, то да, разница есть. Всё зависит от "уровня защиты" объекта, который создаётся этими методами.

Для начала - что общего.
И там и там создаются объекты интерфейса List, методы изменения (содержимого или размера) которых выбрасывают исключения. Это методы `add`, `remove`, `set`, `sort` и т.д.

Теперь об отличиях.

Метод `Collections.unmodifiableList` принимает в качестве аргумента другой list и хранит ссылку на него внутри новой реализации, оборачивая вызовы вышеперечисленных методов и бросая екцепшн. Но при этом изменив исходный лист мы получим изменение и в его unmodifiable отображении.

Библиотека Guava имеет 2 типа статических методов для создания отображения - `of` и `copyOf`. Первая группа методов принимает varargs элементов, которые будут содержаться в отображении, вторая группа - разные типы коллекции, iterable, list и т.п., из которых делается копия для хранения в отображении. Т.е. за исключением рефлексии невозможно повлиять на контент и размер отображения модифицируя источник.

props и cons:

`Collections.unmodifiableList`

малое потребление памяти

модификация отображения при воздействии на источник

может содержать nulls

`Guava`

большое потребление памяти

защита отображения при модификации источника

не может содержать nulls

Какой вариант выбирать - зависит от целей и баланса память/производительность/защита.

Ну и напоследок ещё парочка подобных методов.

`List.of()` - наверное полная аналогия Guava `ImmutableList.of()`. Если применить конструкцию (например для типа данных Integer) `List.of(source.toArray(new Integer[0]))`, то это будет аналогия метода Guava `ImmutableList.copyOf()`.

`Arrays.asList()` - создаёт list, содержимое которого можно модифицировать (методы `set`, `sort`),  а размер нет (`add`, `remove` и т.д.)